# Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.(while selecting multiple columns)

Tags: apache-2.2, php

am using `apache 2.2`.i have written this code
when am trying to run it my browser is failing to run it ,it's showing

```
 This webpage is not available
 The connection to localhost was interrupted.
 Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.
```

following is my php code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_STRICT | E_ALL);
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/db.inc.php' ;
$sql="select post_id,post_title,post_desc,post_date,course,semester,firstname,lastname FROM wbut_forum_posts left join users on post_by = email ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 25";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql );

if (!$result)
{
    include_once "wall.html.php";
    echo'<tr><td align="center"> OOOOPPPPPSSS!!!SORRY,UNABLE TO DISPLAY LATEST 25 TOPICS</td></tr>';
    exit();
}
$allposts = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $allposts[] = array( 'p_id' => $row['post_id'],'p_title' => $row['post_title'],'p_desc' => $row['post_desc'],'p_date' => $row['post_date'],'p_course' => $row['course'],'p_semester' => $row['semester'],'p_firstname' => $row['firstname'],'p_lastname' => $row['lastname']);
}
foreach ($allposts as $posts) :
?>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
<tr>
<td align="left"> <span class="style5"><?php echo $posts[p_firstname] . " " . $posts[p_laststname] ; ?></span></td>
<?php
 $id=urlencode($posts[p_id]);
 $title=urlencode($posts[p_title]);
 $date=urlencode($posts[p_date]);
 $course=urlencode($posts[p_course]);
 $semester=urlencode($posts[p_semester]);
 $firstname=urlencode($posts[p_firstname]);
 $lastname=urlencode($posts[p_lastname]);
 ?>
 <td align="center" >
        <a href="view.html.php?id=<?php echo "$id" ?>&amp;title=<?php echo "$title" ?>&amp;date=<?php echo "$date" ?>&amp;course=<?php echo "$course" ?>&amp;semester=<?php echo "$semester" ?>&amp;firstname=<?php echo "$firstname" ?>&amp;lastname=<?php echo "$lastname" ?>&amp;" title="VIEW POST">
            VIEW THE FULL POST AND REPLY HERE
        </a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <span class="style6"><?php echo $posts[p_title] ; ?></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right"><?php echo $posts[p_date] ; ?></td>
    <td align="center">
        <PRE>RELATED COURSE  : <span class="style7"><?php echo $posts[p_course] ; ?></span> AND RELATED SEMESTER :  <?php echo $posts[p_semester] ; ?></PRE>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><span class="style17"><?php echo $posts[p_desc] ; ?></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**ERROR:**

**This webpage is not available
     The connection to localhost was interrupted.
     Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.**
is it problem of my apache???if so then how to fix it..

Answer (score 0):

This is a Google Chrome error message - i.e. it's certainly got nothing to do with your PHP code.

You've not provided any information about what OS this is running on. It happens with alarming frequency on Microsoft Windows with a several products sold as ant-malware.

Is there anything in your apache error logs? Firewall logs?

Best way to investigate further is to look at the dataflows with a packet analyser (e.g. wireshark) but you have to know what you're looking at.